# Sharepoint make custom column available in edit view

Tags: sharepoint

I have a Sharepoint form that posts documents in a Sharepoint site on sharepoint.com. I'm able to modify the views by clicking on the three dots and selecting 'modify this view'

In this edit view there is an option to add and remove columns which appears to be a list of standard columns common to applications.

My problem is I have a column which I believe was created with the form (I didn't create it) - is it possible to add this column to this list in edit view so i can include it in the standard view and allow people to sort by this data?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems not to be about programming.

Comment: It sounds like you have a customized form and that the data in that extra field is not necessarily being saved in the SharePoint list. Do you know if the custom form is an InfoPath form?

Comment: I don't know much about the form, though InfoPath does ring a bell - I'm not sure how I can check if this is the case or not.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to allow management of content types.  You can then edit the fields that show on your new/edit/display forms.

Click advanced settings -> enable management of content types -> click the content type and hide or remove the fields you need.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this information, i appreciate it so much.

I located the screen above under library > Library settings > advanced settings

I then went into  library > Library settings > Add columns from existing site columns and added the field (Due Date)

I now see the field when i go into "modify this view" which is great - i added it to be visible and now its there, but no data.

on the form / document it has data, but each line in the standard document list view does not have any data for this field.